# Puzzle : Find minimum resource allocation on multiple of 10 or 12 only

Tags: code-challenge, math

I have two types of notebook .

- 10 problems could be solved in one page, in the first notebook.
- 12 problems could be solved in one page, in the second notebook.

For  given n problems I have to  use pages in such a way that no space from both notebook should be wasted ever .
Taking consideration that I have to use minimum pages also . Output should return number of pages need for solving all problem , if not passible it should return -1.

**Example :**

```
Problem count :  10

Output : 1 (one page from first notebook)

Problem Count :12

Output :1 (one page from second notebook)

Problem Count : 5

Output : -1 (Not possible)

Problem Count : 22

Output : 2(one from first notebook + one from second notebook)

Problem Count: 23

Output:-1(not possible)
```

Comment: What is your winning criterion? You've tagged it as [code-challenge] and [popularity-contest], but the two tags are mutually exclusive. Please read their tag excerpts to know what they mean, and decide which tag to use.

Comment: If your question is a code-challenge you need to specify an objective winning criterion so as to decide the winner. You need to write something like a scoring method, and include it in your post. You can look at other [code-challenge] questions and see what that means.

Answer (score 1):

### [Sage](http://sagemath.org/), 174 bytes

Golfed because the question does not specify a winning criterion.

```py
def n(k):
 p=MixedIntegerLinearProgram(None,0);x=p.new_variable(0,0,1);p.add_constraint(x[0]*10+x[1]*12==k);p.set_objective(x[0]+x[1])
 try:return p.solve()
 except:return -1
```

**Brief explanation:**

This uses the Sage built-in linear program solver (because why not). `MILP(None,0)` specifies it to use the default solver for minimization (same as `MILP(maximization=False)` but shorter). `new_variable(0,0,1)` is the same as `new_variable(integer=True)`. When there is no solution, the solver will throw an exception: `MIPSolverException: 'GLPK : There is no feasible integer solution to this Linear Program'`, which is caught and `-1` is returned.

**Sample IO:**

```
sage: n(10)
1.0
sage: n(12)
1.0
sage: n(5)
-1
sage: n(22)
2.0
sage: n(23)
-1
sage: n(9999999)
-1
sage: n(1<<31)
178956971.0
```

<sub>*Note that this submission may not work for some very large numbers because of floating point rounding issues.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 83

```
$l=$ARGV[0];for$i(0..$l){for$j(0..$l){if(10*$i+12*$j==$l){print$i+$j;exit}}}print-1
```

With the lack of clear winning criteria, I've decided to go for golf. I'll probably change that once things are clarified.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

```js
n=k=>{for(i=0;i<=k;i++)for(j=0;j<=k;j++)if(10*i+12*j==k)return i+j;return-1}
```

A JavaScript inplementation of the Perl answer. Simple `for` loops, not very interesting.